# Permission denied to view a folder. I copied a file from one folder to the current folder

Tags: permissions, directory

I am new user of Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu version 12.10 in virtual box.

The problem.

I downloaded a file called pcre in to `/home/downloads`.

I created a folder in pcre in home folder and moved the pcre file from download folder to pcre folder

I then copied the folder `/home/dinesh/pcre` to `/usr/local/src/snort/snorttmp` using the command

```
cp -a /home/dinesh/pcre  /usr/local/src/snort/snorttmp
```

When I am trying to access snorttmp folder, a message is displayed

> " The folder contents could not be displayed. You do not have the
>   permissions necessary to view the contents of "snorttmp".

Before copying pcre file into the snorttmp, I had access to snorttmp and was able to view the files present in snorttmp folder.

I then tried to see my files through the terminal

```
root@dinesh-VirtualBox: /usr/local/src/snort/snorttmp# ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1   root    root    5189146 Jan 24 00:18  2787                    
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root    19659   Jan 28 16:29  index.html           
drwxrwxr-x  2   dinesh  dinesh     4096 Jan 28 20:18  pcre          
drwxr-xr-x  10  root    root       4096 Jan 1  00:08  snort-2.9.6.0          
drwxrwxr-x  6   dinesh  dinesh     4096 Jan 28 20:20  SnortRules        
drwxr-xr-x  2   root    root       4096 Jan 28 16:18  snorttmp
```

I find few of the files are marked in blue while the other files are displayed in white.

The files that were displayed in blue when I did ls -l are

pcre
snort-2.9.6.0
SnortRules
snorttmp

2787 and index.html are displayed in white.

Kindly let me know what should be done to get permission to view my files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to get at that folder through the GUI.  Check the permissions of the snorttmp and snort directories:

```
sudo ls -al /usr/local/src/snort/ | grep snorttmp

sudo ls -al /usr/local/src/ | grep snort
```

If those look ok (`drwxr-xr-x  root root`), then there must be something more elusive going on.  In that case, you can always try running Nautilus (file explorer) with elevated permissions (*you also might first have to install gksu* `sudo apt-get install gksu`):

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Comment: I did 

sudo ls -al /usr/local/src/snort/ | grep snorttmp                

Result

drwx------  14  root  root  4096  Jan  28  20:43   snorttmp             


I also did

sudo ls -al /usr/local/src/ | grep snort             

Result

drwxr-xr-x   3   root   root  4096  Jan  28  17:17   snort              

I installed gksu using sudo apt-get install gksu

After this I was able to get into the snorttmp folder. I was able to see only two files in the snorttmp folder - 2787 and index.html file. The other files such as pcre, SnortRules, snort-9.6.0 were not visible.

Comment: I am able to see the other files now thanks BryceAtNetworks23

Comment: @Dinesh that is great to hear.  If my answer helped you at all, please make sure to either "accept" it, +1 it, or both.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me.Please tell me how do I do +1.

Comment: @Dinesh You can +1 an answer once you have 15 reputation.  So let's hope someone else +1's your question...

Answer (score 0):

Add `sudo` in front of the command, you want to run as super user. It should look like

```
sudo cp -a /home/dinesh/pcre /usr/local/src/snort/snorttmp
```

Then enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I did 
sudo cp -a /home/dinesh/pcre /usr/local/src/snort/snorttmp      
But still I could not access the snorttmp folder